# How to make an object move in increments

Tags: java, bluej

I'm stuck at how to write code to make an object move in increments to the desired amount and not just jump straight to the end goal.

e.g.

Move an object from 1 - 500 (x,y, coordinates [0,1] to [0,500]) by going 1, 2, 3, 4, 5........
and not 1 to 500 in one movement?

```
      else if(direction == 'D'){
         xInc = 0;
         yInc = 1;
         this.setXPos(this.xPos +(distance * xInc));
         this.setYPos(this.yPos +(distance * yInc));
         this.alignAll();
         this.delay(20);
      }

   }
```

Here is my full code I have so far any help would be greatly appreciated TIA.

Comment: What is `this`? Could you post a [reprex]? This isn't something that could be copy/pasted and run.

Comment: @sleepToken my full code is below

Comment: Please instead *edit* your original question - since your full code is not an answer.

Comment: @sleepToken it won't let me

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you read up on a [reprex]. There are missing classes - and no `main` method so I assume you have some driver program. What are you using to display your figure? Again - we can't copy/paste your StickFigure class and run it.

Comment: I totally agree with @sleepToken, You should provide all the clues to people so it's easier to provide help. I just try to help you by adding your code in the edit. but seems like there 's some missing class. Anyway, I will try to answer from what i have in mind but feel free to add some other class for other people after you.

Comment: @sleepTokenNo sorry didn't read up on this before hand but have now and I'm not sure what the minimum I could have posted to get help.

Comment: @EFOEThe only other classes I have in the project are to produce the Circle, Triangle and Rectangle which I thought didn't need to be shown here?

Comment: I've updated my question to show exactly what I'm asked to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a loop between your assignment something like :

```
  if(direction == 'R'){
  xInc = 1;
  yInc = 0;
  for(int index= 0; index <= distance;index ++){
    this.setXPos(this.xPos +(xInc));
    this.setYPos(this.yPos +(yInc));
    this.alignAll();
    this.delay(20);  
  }

}
```

I also strongly recommend you to externalize this function, since it will be almost the same depending on your direction.

Comment: I have tried this for 'R' and I'm getting the error "not a statement"

Comment: Sorry I paste the wrong code can you try the new one, please.